# InheritanceApp.java:37: error: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: java

I am getting an error on the following code:

```
public class InheritanceApp {

    class Product {

        // atributes
        int p_id;
        String name;
        double price;

        // constructor
        Product() {
            System.out.println(">> Product Object Constructed");
        }

        // method
        public void setProductDetails(int p_id, String name, double price) {

            this.p_id = p_id;
            this.name = name;
            this.price = price;
        }

        // Read data from product object
        public void showProductDeatails() {
            System.out.println("---------Product Id: " + p_id + "-----------");
            System.out.println("Name : \t" + name);
            System.out.println("Price : \t" + price);
            System.out.println("------------------------------------------------");
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Creat object : product
        Product product = new Product();

        // Writting data into an object
        product.setProductDetails(100, "Nike", 6700.60);

        // Reading data from an object
        product.showProductDeatails();

    }

}
```

the error says:

> InheritanceApp.java:37: error: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context
>   Product product = new Product();

Comment: Declare `class Product` as `static class Product` (easiest) or initialize your variable with `Product product = new InheritanceApp().new Product();`.

Comment: or don't put it in another class, but in it's own Java file. Why do you call this 'InheritanceApp'? there is no inheritance involved.

Answer (score 1):

Java Nested classes are divided into two types: static nested classes and non-static nested classes (also known as "inner"). A static nested class is the same as any other top-level class and is nested for only packaging convenience, whilst inner classes are associated with the particular instance.

Using a static nested class:

```
OuterClass.StaticClass obj = new OuterClass.StaticClass();
```

Using an inner class:

```
OuterClass outObj = new OuterClass();
OuterClass.InnerClass inObj = outerObject.new InnerClass();
```

Now depending on your use case, use whatever approach you need. For example:

```
InheritanceApp inheritanceApp = new InheritanceApp();
InheritanceApp.Product product = InheritanceApp.new Product();
```

Find more information in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html).